# why optional typing in Dart?

Tags: generics, covariance, dart, type-systems

http://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/dartLangSpec.pdf

The language spec for Dart mentions below

> Dart supports optional typing based on interface types.
>   The type system is unsound, **due to the covariance of generic types**. This is
>   a deliberate choice (and undoubtedly controversial). Experience has shown that
>   **sound type rules for generics fly in the face of programmer intuition**. It is ..

- Can someone elaborate further on the reason type system is unsound?
- What was the Dart lang spec writers thinking when they say sound type rules for generics fly in the face of intuition?

Comment: This article was just added to dartlang.org which should address some of these questions: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/why-dart-types/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What was the Dart lang spec writers thinking when they say sound type rules for generics fly in the face of intuition?

Take a look at the related questions to the right of this one. I see:

- Why is `List<Number>` not a sub-type of `List<Object>`?
- Why generic interfaces are not co/contravariant by default?
- Why can't I assign a `List<Derived>` to a `List<Base>`?
- Why cant I cast from a `list<MyClass>` to `List<object>`?
- Why `Animals[] animals = new Cat[5]` compiles, but `List<Animal> animals = new List<Cat>()` does not?

While covariance isn't sound (for many mutable types), it is the behavior that many programmers intuitively expect when they first start working with generic types.

Comment: That's really weird, since the soundness of co(ntra)variance depends only on the method/function/property signatures for such an object. It's something you could infer even (though that would lead to many "gotchas", where adding methods could break the variance behavior of the type). --- All in all, it's fine, but it seems immensely strange to specially permit array covariance and no other parametric types.

Comment: Actually, following [Eric Lippert's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/29/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-seven-why-do-we-need-a-syntax-at-all.aspx), I don't think you can actually infer variance without running into problems.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about cycles. But even here, Eric gives up too early. He says "'both invariant', '+T, +U' and '-T, -U/ all produce programs which would be typesafe. How would we choose?". He missed a case. "+-T, +-U". Really, this code has defined only two meaningful types: "interface IFrob : IBlah {} interface IBlah { IFrob Frob(); }") / btw, you answered the _original_ question perfectly. Don't take any of this as a critique :-)

Comment: @munificent - All your List examples are wrong in case the List class is immutable. In such a case, it's perfectly acceptable for List<Derived> to be a subtype of List<Base>.

It's not that covariance isn't sound. You got it wrong. The problem is that not all generic types should be covariant. Mutable classes should be invariant. A function's parameters in a Function type is naturally contravariant, while the return type is covariant, so a function of 1 parameter should have the type Function<-T,+R>.

Comment: Right, but in the questions I'm referencing, List is *not* immutable. The problem is that even with mutable collections, user's intuition is still that they should be covariant.

Answer (score 9):

From Gilad Bracha [1]:

> You can write a tool that will scream bloody murder about these
>   things, but what you can’t do is stop people from running their
>   programs.

Or, in other words [2]:

> The
>   problem is that expressing type flow fully and explicitly is more
>   difficult for most programmers than writing code that passes values
>   around and deals with runtime type errors when and if they happen. The
>   word chosen for this difference in difficulty is that the latter is
>   more "intuitive" than the former - I don't think it's a particularly
>   bad choice of word. The phenomenon is one of the biggest reasons
>   dynamic languages have become a lot more popular over recent years, a
>   rejection of complexity in specifying static types.
>
> It's like there's
>   another triangle tradeoff: expressive, sound, simple: choose any two
>   for your type system. Almost everyone is unwilling to forgo
>   expressiveness - the object graphs weaved in modern software can be
>   quite tangled indeed - while any language that hopes to have
>   large-scale success cannot start out being anything but fairly simple.
>   So they give up some measure of (statically-typed) soundness, and
>   expect lots of runtime type errors during debugging and testing.

[1] http://blog.sethladd.com/2011/11/transcription-of-quick-tour-of-dart-by.html

[2] http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4377#comment-67589

Answer (score 2):

More concretely, as far as unsoundness goes, generic types are covariant. So a List of Strings  can be passed to something that expects a List of Object. This is not typesafe, because the thing that expects a list of Object could conceivably try to add something to the List which wasn't a String. But telling people that when you have B as a subclass of A, but Collection<B> is not a subtype of Collection<A> is quite non-intuitive.